# python code for a bounce ball game, don't know what's wrong

Tags: python, tkinter

a bounce ball game using tkinter. When I run it, the ball will move but the bar which is supposed to be controlled by the left and right arrow won't move. I don't know what's wrong with it. Plz help.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This is what shows up in python shell after i run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/linziyi/Downloads/PythonForKidsCode/chapter14/bounce9.py", line 79, in <module>
    tk.update_idletasks()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1019, in update_idletasks
    self.tk.call('update', 'idletasks')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Comment: The `application is destroyed` because you have `while 1:`. If you change it to a conditional that is not always `True`, you won't get that error after the code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't work well with infinite loops, since it has its own infinite `mainloop`. What you want to do is use the `after` method, which calls a function after an amount of time. Try to replace the while loop with the following code:

```
def update_game():
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.after(10, update_game)

tk.after(10, update_game)
tk.mainloop()
```

This will call `update_game` every 10 milliseconds, without blocking Tkinter's `mainloop`.

Comment: But the bar still won't move...  :(

Comment: Using the exact code you posted and replacing the while loop with the code I posted, the bar moves just as expected for me. Do you get any error messages?